# synchronization not working after making object synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

I have synchronized Integer object a and I am expecting output 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
but still it is giving me other output.Where is the problem as I have synchronized the variable where each thread was trying to access.

```
package thread;
public class BasicThread extends Thread {
    static Integer a=new Integer(0);
    void incr() {
        synchronized (a) {          
            a++;
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        incr();
        incr();
        incr();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        BasicThread bt=new BasicThread();
        BasicThread bt1=new BasicThread();
        BasicThread bt2=new BasicThread();

        bt.start();
        bt1.start();
        bt2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What output did you get?

Comment: @james making my function static too solves my problem.Is this right way and what type of problem can occur making my function static .            static Integer a=new Integer(0);
  synchronized static void incr()
 {
   {
   a++;
   System.out.println(a);
  
   }  
 }

Comment: Adding `static` to the declaration of your `incr()` function won't change what your program does.  It doesn't depend on any instance variables, so it makes no difference whether it's an instance method or a `static` method.

Comment: The problem with your program is that the statement, `a++`, _assigns_ the variable, `a`.  That is to say, before `a++`, the variable refers to one object, and after `a++` it refers to a different object.  That means your threads potentially are synchronizing on _different objects_, and that will not prevent them from running concurrently in the `synchronized` block.

Answer (score 5):

Please note: Integer **objects** are immutable. So, what happens here is: every time you do a "a++" ... the compiler actually does auto-boxing; and in the end ... a **new** Integer object is created.

In order for your code to work, your lock (the object you are synchronizing on) **must be the same** for all calls to the method.

In other words: a reference to an object that is constantly changed ... is not a good candidate to be used as lock. Instead, do something like:

```
private final static Object LOCK = new Object();
```

(where usage of **final** helps to ensure that this object reference will not change over time) and then:

```
synchronized(LOCK)
```

Comment: You could emphasize that the `final` in your `LOCK` declaration makes that kind of mistake much less likely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use a unique Object to synchronize on. When you change your Integer a new one is created since they're immutable.

Example:

```
public class BasicThread extends Thread {
    static Integer a = new Integer(0);
    private static String ab = "";

    void incr() {
        synchronized (ab) {
            a++;
            System.out.println(a);

        }
    }

    public void run() {

        incr();
        incr();
        incr();
    }
}
```